# Return a pure json error in Tornado

Tags: python, tornado

```
def get(self):
    self.set_status(400, '["reason"]')
    self.finish()
    return
```

When you get this response you can get `response.error.message` which has the message `HTTP 400: ["reason"]`. But what if you wanted a pure json response as an error. What would be the best way to get that?

Comment: When you get this response where? In another Tornado instance?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11694124/tornado-write-a-jsonp-object

Comment: When you call the 'get' of that requesthandler.

Comment: @monkey, related yes. But this is about returning an error response with the right status code.

Comment: Your question is about returning json only - what do you expect your json to look like? What do you expect your response to look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second argument to `set_status()` is the "reason" string, i.e. the "Not Found" in `HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found`. It's human-readable, not machine readable, and many HTTP clients simply discard it. You should only use this parameter when you are sending a status code that is not found in the standard list.

Instead, when you want to send a JSON message along with an error, call `self.set_status(code)`, and then write your output as usual into the body:

```
self.set_status(400)
self.finish({"reason": reason})
```